# Являются ли пользователь и учётная запись отдельными сущностями?

Tags: архитектура, проектирование

Не ругайте сильно, если мой вопрос некорректный. Бывает ли так, что при разработке требований к ПО необходимо (или полезнее) представить пользователя и учётную запись отдельными (но взаимосвязанными) сущностями или это единая сущность? Или же нужно исходить из контекста?

Comment: Конечно. Например, суперпользователь в *nix (root, id = 0) может иметь несколько разных login name c разными паролями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от контекста.

Более того, даже одна и та же сущность реального мира в разных модулях системы может быть представлена разными сущностями. Посмотрите на понятие [Bounded Context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) в DDD/микросервисах.

Каждый модуль может по своему видеть, *что* такое пользователь и соответсвенно моделировать его по своему.

Comment: А в контексте аутентификации/авторизации в веб-приложении, в виде какой сущности можно рассматривать человека, находящегося на странице ввода логина и пароля до момента отправки и после успешной авторизации. То есть, может ли быть представлен какой либо сущностью не авторизованный пользователь?

Comment: Все зависит от того, для чего это нужно. Может быть представлен сущностью **АнонимныйПользователь**, например.